# Get rid of duplicate songs on phone when using Google Music

Tags: google-play-music

I've uploaded my mp3s to Google Music. I also physically have the files on my phone. But now when I use the Google Music app it shows the songs on my sd card *and* the songs I've uploaded to the cloud.

Apart from deleting the files on my phone, is there a way to tell Google not to sync songs I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think that there is no other way as to simply delete the files on your Android device.** Make sure you have a copy of the files on your PC or an external HD. I am not sure if one can download the mp3s easily from the Google music cloud. **You have the files in Google musics cloud, why do you need them on the device too? The music App will cache the files on the device for fast/offline access.**

Comment: If I want songs offline that I haven't cached yet then I can't get them.  I did notice however that if you long click a song/artist/album you can tick a box that says "Available offline" so I guess that's how to "sync" files physically with their cloud.

Comment: You can also mark whole playlists as offline available

Comment: The Music Manager now has a tool to download "purchased" music from the cloud.